# Cant Access Php Myadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Previously I could access Php Myadmin using `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`
But today i can not access. When I go to this url it shows nothing , no error , just a blank page.Now don't know what to do.

I use `windows 7` as my OS and `Firefox` browser.

Comment: **inspect element** and check what error you get in consol. You **start your server ( xampp or wampp ) properly????** First do this if not.

Comment: have you checked your server logs or php logs for possible errors that might lead you to the problem?

Comment: When I inspect element and I got error like bellow : 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
message...abd367b (line 245)
ReferenceError: PMA_commonParams is not defined
/phpmyadmin/ (line 2)
ReferenceError: AJAX is not defined

Comment: Make sure you running xampp or wampp server with apache and mysql running. Some times the localhost wont work as expected try to go for 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, which may work fine.